# MVC Model Validation is not triggering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have the following in my Service Model

```
<DisplayName("Description")>
<DataType(DataType.Text)>
<StringLength(30)>
Public Property Description() As String
    Get
        Return m_Description
    End Get
    Set
        m_Description = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Description As String
```

And this in my Partial View

```
@ModelType CDB.ServiceDetail

@Code
    Dim sb as New StringBuilder    

    'Description
        sb.Append("<div class=""rowBlock"">")
        sb.Append("<div class=""rowTitle"">")
        sb.Append(Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Description))
        sb.Append(":</div><div class=""rowValue"">")
        sb.Append(Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Description))
        sb.Append("</div>")
        sb.Append("</div>")
End Code

<div id="divService" name="divService" style="width:100%">

    @Html.Raw(sb.ToString())

</div>
```

If I type more than 30 characters for the Description it does not error. Any ideas why?  I'm using MVC5 if this is relevant.

UPDATE
My scripts in _layout master.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/jszip.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")"></script>
```

Comment: When you check the ModelState.IsValid in the controller, does it show that the model is valid?

Comment: @DavidY I'm new to MVC... I thought that these settings did client side validation and from examples I've seen the validation happens client side. Example... https://joeylicc.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/asp-net-mvc-model-validation-using-data-annotations/

Comment: They will do client side validation, but you can also do server side validation. If the server side validation were to work I would then think there may be a problem with how the jQuery is set up for the partial view. Usually a view inherits a shared view, ie the _layout.cshtml file which by default has the jquery includes for validation. I suspect this may be missing in the partial view set up.

Comment: I think the Microsoft article will be a more complete example of the entire process. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

Comment: @DavidY... I've updated my question adding the references to scripts that exist in _layout. Do I have any missing?

Comment: You should be able to add a bundle for jQuery validation to the view itself. Assuming it has been bundled.

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the script render for the jqueryval plugin to your partial view.

```
@section Scripts {
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

These bundles are set up by default in the mvc template in AppStart.BundleConfig.

VB syntax:

```
@section Scripts 
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
End Section
```

Comment: This did the trick... have added the vb razor syntax for others.